# How to get a node reference in a binary tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes

I'm doing this assignment right now and one of the methods I need to write is getting a node reference given a certain String label.

One of the fields in my node contains a String called label and I want to check my entire tree to see if a particular node contains that specific String.

How would I go about doing this?

So far I have a method called `getNodeReference` that takes a String label and I want to do something like:

```
  if(root != contain the String) {
   --search the left children, middle children, then right children (I guess its a ternary tree)
  }

 if (left.node != contain the String) {
  --keep searching left, if you cant find it go on to middle. etc.
  }
```

Comment: I suggest posting code rather than talking about it.

Comment: You can either do a breadth-first search or a depth-first search. The choice is yours. Had it been a binary tree, you could have made a binary search tree (considering String has a compareTo method). This would have made searching a lot faster for you.

Comment: Either do a traversal or a BFS / DFS.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of operation you are referring to are called **Tree Traversals**.  A good reference on how to perform them is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

But an example could be (in pseudocode):

```
Set up a queue.
Enqueue the root.
While the queue is not empty:
    Dequeue an item.
    If the item matches, return it.
    Else
        Iterate over the children of the item, enqueuing them
        in order from left to right.
```

This is referred to as a **Breadth First Search**.  It is up to you to figure out how to do a similar **Depth First Search**, but I'll give you a hint.  A stack might be involved.